# Google play orders

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-subscription

I have an app that contains in-app products and subscriptions. App already that send orders ids when a user subscribe. 
Now, i want to compare my history with the google play orders.

Is there an API to get the list of all google play orders ?

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The Play Store already manages the payments, the expiration or renewal of the subscriptions, grace period or the purchase of in-app products, in exchange they keep 30% or 15% of the price.

Your application should only call `billingClient.queryPurchases()` periodically to know what products the user owns, or which subscriptions are active.

I don't see any sense about maintain a parallel control in a separate history.